# Error when updating texlive 2015

Tags: packages, texlive, windows

When I want to update packages of texlive 2015 I get this error? what is the problem?

```
tlmgr update --list

The locale codeset (cp720) isn't one that perl can decode, stopped at  
C:\texlive \2015\tlpkg\tlperl\lib/Encode/Locale.pm line 123. Compilation 
failed in require at C:\texlive\2015\tlpkg\tlperl\lib/LWP/UserAgent. pm 
line 1001.
```

Comment: Try first `tlmgr --gui`.

Comment: @Sigur When I type  `tlmgr --gui` I get exactly same error.

Comment: Imho you should better ask on the texlive mailing list. It sounds as if the perl script doesn't expect your code page. You could perhaps get around it by locally changing the codepage with `chcp`.

Comment: I have the same  problem with my texlive 2015 on Windows 8

Comment: @Ali `tlmgr --gui` => `tlmgr gui`, the syntax changed some time ago.

Comment: @Ali you can change the code page like what I am done, enter command prompt and just type `chcp 850`, and  the problem disappears,

Comment: To make the change of chcp  permanent you can  take a look at this method [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432545/change-codepage-in-cmd-permanently)

Comment: @KeksDose tlmgr --gui works for me (TL2015 Win8)

Comment: @KeksDose That makes no change.

Comment: @Ali Yes, the old command still works, but it is deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like a bug in Texlive 2015 on windows  for number of the active console code page **cp720**.

- You can change this code with command prompt by inserting `chcp nnn`, where `nnn` specifies the code page ( example :  `chcp 850`), you can find a list of cp [here](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Code_page).
  but you must repeat the same steps each time you want to open `tlmgr`.
- You can automate the previous steps by inserting the command `chcp nnn` directly in the file `tlmgr.bat`, in your case you can find it on  this path:
  C:\texlive\2015\bin\win32.

  `@echo off`

  `chcp 850`

Comment: Thank you very much, no other solution was working. I am using windows 8.1 with strawberry perl 5.2 but still the issue was there. I was able to use Tex Live Manager 2015 by making the change you suggested. I add the chcp 850 line on the 2nd line of the file tlmgr.bat